# F# 3.1 preview in VS2012/Windows 8

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-8, f#

Does anyone know of any way to make this happen, or if it's even possible? I'd like the play with 3.1, but as far as i can tell, F# 3.1 requires VS2013 requires Windows-8.1-preview requires wiping-my-computer-to-reinstall-windows-8.1-proper-when-it-comes-out, the last of which is a rather large inconvenience.

But I still want to try out 3.1; is there any way of getting it (locally, not on some web repl) that lets me use it without the reinstall-operating-system thing?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I also need the Windows 8 Store SDK (since i'm targeting it) and that's probably the component that's Windows-8.1 only I think.

Comment: It is probably possible for someone to install windows 8.1 in a VM and extract the binaries

Comment: That's probably possible, but setting up an entire operating system in a VM just to run visual studio just to run F# seems like a bit of a waste (both in effort and in cpu/ram resources). The alternative is just waiting the weeks/months until 8.1 RTM comes out.

Comment: I installed VS 2013 preview on Windows 7 without problem.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you believe that you need Windows 8.1 to run VS 2013?  It looks to me like Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8 are both supported (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/2013-editions#product-2013-summary)), and Visual Studio 2013 installs side-by-side with VS 2012.

Comment: I believe VS works, but the VS Windows 8 Store SDK doesn't (probably should have stated that). I too have VS 2013 without the windows 8 store SDK installed on my machine next to my VS2013.